# Using a Color channel with Camera + Light rotation to influence material [EEVEE]

Tags: eevee-render-engine, color, npr

**EDIT: Here's a PDF that should help, http://pds26.egloos.com/pds/201712/21/31/GuilltyGearXrd_shader.pdf**

This is hard to explain and I've once made a question about this before,

but I'm doing EEVEE cel-shading and trying to use a texture's blue and red color channel along with a drivers for light rotation to achieve a "specular" effect and things are not working too well to get the desired effect.

---

To start, the game's specular effect I'm replicating in question uses the blue channel to determine how

"easy" the specular appears based on both camera AND light rotation.

**[ Spec appearance threshold = How much blue coloration exists]**

Here is an example of the view/camera affecting where the spec appears (focus on the shoulder and black rims of the coat), and it always tries to follow the camera's view, even in shadow.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVJvV.jpg

And here is when the light source is rotated:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ht4HW.jpg

As for what the red channel does, it just determines how bright or intense the spec appears color-wise.

More red = Brighter color

Less red = very faint color

**What matters most is the blue channel, and how I can get both light rotation info and camera info to work together to get the proper effect.**

What's frustrating most and proof that I'm not getting close in EEVEE is the fact the shoulders are rendered either fully-colored or not at all with the specular, and the shoulder UVs also look like *this* on the channel texture:

[image: Barely any blue?]

Which is to say barely there is ANY blue, so Im even more at a loss on how to do this. :/

Blue appears way more on the coat rims UVs and is appropriately easy to see when in-game though.

**To sum it up**

- Rotating the light source removes or adds spec depending on the angle.
- But moving the camera or character still shows that spec can show up anyways, so the light source doesn't entirely dictate whether it can appear, that much is certain.
- More red = More bright
- More blue = Easier to appear

I'd be grateful for ANY assistance since I thought I solved my old problem long ago, but it turns out I was wrong.

I have a .blend file for reference too since it's usually difficult for anyone to understand how this shader works :p

Feel free to try and achieve the spec effect.

[image]

Comment: Hi. I think some test blend file will help people here to start from a valid test case (including packed textures). Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just added it a second ago lol

Comment: You've probably already looked at Lightning Boy's excellent [Toon Shading Series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpWI2rU8iF0&list=PLZ7TSA6MfgM_IX3qZslXx_QdvLLDZHZGx), which uses similar techniques?

Comment: What is the purpose of adding sun rotations as vector with position (geometry node)?

Comment: Apologies if this comes across as a very naive question. At first sight, you're doing all your incidence-angle (eye, surface normal, light) calculations by hand. Why are you not letting  shaders do those for you, by using  _Shader to RGB_ nodes?

Comment: @lemon Sun rotations are to allow the base shading to take place, and the spec movement looks as though it uses the same math involved with the light rotation but also somehow combines it with camera view. I took the "normalize light" output from the divide node and plugged that in the "greater than" node with the blue channel and got a relatively balanced spec effect, but dont know how to throw in the cam to make it useful :p https://imgur.com/a/IWUzuFq

Comment: @RobinBetts Sorry to say that it's an uninformed assumption, but thats understandable lol. The point is to replicate 2D animation and have complete control over how character's look. It's for a cel-shaded fighting game, and each animation is animated like traditional 2D, so lighting control is extremely important. If you or anyone else needs more elaboration I'd be happy to give it :)

Comment: Agree with @lemon, just as an example, it's hard to make sense of that part of your tree. Adding a 3-component rotation to a 3-component World Space shading-point location? As a demo.. the object is lit differently if the sun is rotated by 0, 360, 720 Z degrees, despite those all being the same direction. Or, despite the Sun Lamp being at infinity, and so _its_ location having no effect, the model is lit differently depending on its location in World Space, in a way that does not relate to the location of the lamp, camera, or anything else.